# Is there any other parameter like `this` in div name.first in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see some thing like

`$(#content).children(".p:first");`

call the first `<p>` tag, except `first`, Is there any other parameter? thanks.

exaple:

```
<div id="content">
<p>aaa</p>
<p>bbb</p>
<p>ccc</p>
```

use `$(#content).children(".p:first");` echo

```
<div id="content">
<p>aaa</p>
</div>
```

Is there any `$(#content).children(".p:second");` or `$(#content).children(".p:last");` can be set?

Comment: ".p" is an element with CSS class of "p", not a <p> tag. What are you trying to achieve though, the question is not very clear?

Comment: It looks like you are using jQuery. The syntax is not correct though and does not match with your description. Please clarify your question. As a guess: You might want `.not()`: http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: It's not possible to "call" a <p> tag. What are you trying to accomplish, at the end?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: @cj3333: please make this more clear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Editing `this` to `first` is not enough, you need to rewrite your entire question.

Comment: @jAndy, can I set `$(#content).children(".p:second");`, or `$(#content).children(".p:last");`?

Comment: @cj333: There is only `:first` and `:last`. But you can use e.g. `:eq(1)`.

Comment: @Felix Kling, how to combine `:eq(1)` and `:eq(2)`? I use `$('#content').find('p').eq(1+2);`, still get `:eq(2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any $(#content).children(".p:second"); or $(#content).children(".p:last"); can be set?

`:last` already exists - see the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

`:second` is not there, but could be implemented the easy way:

`$('p:first').next()` or, with a custom selector:

```
$.expr[':'].second= function(
    objNode,
    intStackIndex,
    arrProperties,
    arrNodeStack
    ) {

    return intStackIndex == 1;
}
```

This now allows you to do $('element:second'). See the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6xY6D/

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not absolutley sure what you are trying to do, but I guess you try to query for a specfic index from elements.

So let's assume you want to only grab the first `<p>` tag which is a children from `#content`, that would look like:

```
$('#content p:first')
```

which is aquivalent with

```
$('#content').find('p:first');
```

Same example for the last `<p>` tag:

```
$('#content p:last');
```

If you need to query for an even more specific index, you can apply a `:eq()` selector or the method `.eq()`. Example for the second `<p>` tag:

```
$('#content').find('p').eq(1); // zero based index, 1 is the second node
```

References: [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/), [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: Yep was going to answer `$(#content).children("p").eq(1)` as the way to get second `<p>`. Cheers! :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard,  can I select `$('#content').find('p').eq(1);` and `$('#content').find('p').eq(2);` in the same time? I mean like a `and` or `&` function?

Comment: @cj333: You can use the multiple selector `,`: `$('#content').find('p:eq(1), p:eq(2)')` or if you want to to select a larger range , `:lt` and `:gt` are better, e.g. `$('#content').find('p:gt(0):lt(3)')` Have a look at the selectors documentation for all the possibilites: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/